# Conflicting versions

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am trying to implement gms-vision:18.0.0 in my android project.
I also have 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' in my gradle file. however when i go to sync my project, i get an error

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-23:19 to override.
```

My Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.randomsoft.gmccustomerorders"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'
}
```

any suggestions. It is probable obvious, but I am still fairly new to android programming and I am using Android Studio v3.4.2.

Comment: The google play service library uses androidx. You can't use support libraries and androidx together. You have to migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because of the dependency issue with androidX and appCompact. Google play service support androidX but you are using appCompact in your application which causes manifest not to merge.

I suggest you to update from appCompact to androidX. Which is more reliable now.

I prefer you to refer this link [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

If you still face any issues, please let me know.